# How do you know if a journal is registered on PubMed

Tags: research-undergraduate, medicine

I have several research projects that I am looking to publish but as a young research who is new to the field I am confused as to which journal to submit to.

I know that to get published on PubMed you have to publish on a journal that has been accepted by Medline or PMC. When I look up journals a few say they are affiliated with PubMed but do not specify if this affiliation is through Medline or PMC. Does this mean that mentioning Medline or PMC is not necessary and a PubMed affiliation is all that matters?

In the medical field what seems to matter is being published on PubMed regardless of the journal you published with. This means that submitting to a less known journal which is affiliated with PubMed will guarantee your research is published and available on PubMed. This seems to me that you can make your life easier by always submitting to a less known journal and in the end enjoying the same benefits as a publication in a well known journal.

Is this all that there is to it?

Comment: You added the research-undergraduate tag, so I assume you're in undergrad.  You should really involve an adviser from your faculty in this.  Not only would they help you with improving your research and potentially recommend you for grad programs, they would answer questions like this as well.